# Different ways of expression quotes in Perl

Tags: perl

There are two ways to express quotations:

```
' apostrophe
’ single quotation
```

In Perl, I can match `' apostrophe` using regular expressions. However, I can't match  `’ single quotation` in same way.

What's the problem here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: `There are two ways to express quotations` No, actually there are a lot more than that.

Comment: ’ is no different from any other character when I test it

Comment: Can you show examples of regular expressions working for `'` but failing for `’`?

Comment: It shouldn't be. You can use all sorts of characters to express quotations -provided the leading and trailing character is the same

Comment: Thank for replying. I failed to find ASCII code for the second quotation. And In my project, some Asian contents are involved. Is that mean this problem is related to charset?

Comment: You are supposed to tell us what the problem is, so we can help you fix it. We shouldn't have to read your mind to learn your problem, when you haven't even shown us code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "signle quotation" is the unicode character "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK". When dealing with unicode characters in Perl, be sure to properly identify the encoding of the input and of the script. See [perlunicode - Unicode support in Perl](http://p3rl.org/perlunicode)
 for details.

```
$ perl -CO -E 'use utf8; say for "’Hello’" =~ /(’)/g'
’
’
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $validq1=qq|' apostrophe|;
my $validq2=qq|’ single quotation|;
my $noquotes=qq| teapot|;

my @listofquotechars=qw(' ` " ’);

my $quotematcher="[".join("",map {quotemeta($_)} @listofquotechars)."]";

print $validq1 if ($validq1 =~ /$quotematcher/);
print $validq2 if ($validq2 =~ /$quotematcher/);
print $noquotes if ($noquotes =~ /$quotematcher/);
```

Giving a list of characters you wish to match and then making a character class for a regular expression is one way of doing it, as shown above.